How do I make this part of my code accept multiple answers for the condition to be met?
I haven't touched Python in years and never really learned it in the first place, but I am trying to make a simple question generator for practicing interviewing at my company. My company uses a very large but definite bank of questions, and being able to output them at random will help with interview preparation. This part of the code is at the end and either generates another question if you type "Y" or it gives the pep talk message if anything else is entered. If I wanted to have it accept "y" or something else, what would I need to add to this? I tried a few things, but I can't figure it out.
selected_item = random.choice(lp_questions)
print(selected_item, "\n", "\n")
answer = (input("Would you like another? If so, type 'Y', if not, press any other button"))
if answer == ('Y'):
    print ("\n")
    continue
else:
    print ("\n",
           "You have got this interview in the bag! Come back for more practice if you need it and find someone to do a mock interview with!")
    break


Sounds like maybe you want elif, so elif answer == '<something else>': <other logic>?

You could do something like if answer.upper() in ['Y','YES']: and that would cover 'y','Y','yes','YES','Yes','yEs',etc.

Since there's continue and break in your code, I'll just assume you've already put it in a while loop, and provide only the answer checking part of the code.
"""
we first lower-case the answer by 'answer.lower()', this helps dealing with 'Y'/'y' or 'Yes'/'YEs'/'yEs'

then check if the lower-case answer is in the acceptable answer set

you can create a set by using {} or 'set()'
"""
if answer.lower() in {"y", "yes", "yeah", "true", "great", "of course"}:
    # ... do something when answer is accepted
    continue
else:
    # ... do something when answer not accepted
    break

